# Why I can not received the value in input from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Why i dont get the javascript value after calculation in input tag of my htm given

```
`id=""result"`
```

while i get this in span id and using `document.write(num);`

```
<?php include ('header.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Calculator </title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label style="padding-top: 5px" >Enter Your Per KG Price : </label>
        </td>
        <td  style="padding-left:15px;">
            <input type="tex" id="perkg" placeholder="Enter Per KG Price">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label style="padding-top: 10px" >Enter Your Price : </label>
        </td>
        <td  style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px">
            <input id="required" placeholder="Desired Amount">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" onClick="multiply()" Value="Multiply" />
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>
            <label style="padding-top: 10px" > Weight Given To Customer In Grams </label>
        </td>
        <td  style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px">
            <input id="result"  value="" placeholder="In Grams">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<input type="button" onClick="divideBy()" Value="Divide" />
<p>The Result is : <br>
<span id = "results"></span>
</p>
</form>





<script type="text/javascript">
function multiply()
{
        var num1 = document.getElementById("perkg").value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById("required").value;
        var num =  (1000/num1) * num2;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num;
        //document.write(num); its working

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you have a mismatch of id's `result` vs `results` with an `s`

Comment: that doesnot make differ with one another ?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Clearly the value passed to `getElementById()` needs to match what actually exists which it does not in what is shown. Also check your browser console for errors

Comment: i changed the id name "result" to "hoo" but still doesnot passing the value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update **input** *value attribute* use `value` property instead of `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("result").value = num;
```

Comment: will you give one for favour i'm very thankful to you ?

Comment: sure, go ahead ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375187/how-to-used-order-id-as-invoice-number-and-converting-any-variable-as-gloabal

will you help me out to sort out this, no one give s this answer , i'm veryt thnakful to you please

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: I am watching it

Comment: i'm waiting for your respond! :)

Comment: Accept answer if it really helped you.

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: Hey , Will you give me a one favour please :(